# Move Munin on new server with old data

Tags: munin, rrdtool, graph

I have to move my Munin instance on new server. I've installed from package (Debian) Munin 2.x. All was fine, but ... I copied /var/lib/munin to new server. But after updating munin overwrite old data and i have empty graph :( Could you tell me why? And how i can save old data?

I tried rrdtool dump/restore too. It was the same :(

Thank you for answer and help.

Br,

Comment: Is your munin recording only for the single server?  Is the hostname the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the version of rrd databases ? The last munin want 0003 and you may need to convert them.
Check with a `file` the version.

You may check your logs : you will maybe see something about the owner or something else.

To convert :

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE="/var/lib/munin/DOMAIN/"
cd $SOURCE
for FILE in *rrd
do 
  echo $FILE
  rrdtool dump $FILE > /tmp/$FILE.xml
  NEW=`basename $FILE .xml`
  rm $SOURCE/$NEW
  rrdtool restore /tmp/$FILE.xml $SOURCE/$NEW
  chown munin:munin $SOURCE/$NEW
done
rm /tmp/*.xml
```

Comment: How i can check rrd databases version? On old server i have 1.4.5 and on nw one i tried install the same :(

Comment: Take a RRD file and do a 'file XXX.rrd'

Comment: Old server: RRDTool DB version 0003 / That script convert rrd file?

Comment: I convert copied and the same empty graph :( Any idea?

Comment: Do you have check your logs ?

Comment: I don't have any things wrong in logs. But when i moved /var/www/* to /var/cache/munin/www/, all is fine :) I have old graphs/png and new one is creating too.